# SwiftUI listRowBackground can't animate?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to imitate the normal UITableView behavior of a cell hiliting when you tap it, and then fading out. I'm getting pretty close except:

- `.background()` doesn't fill the entire list cell, it just fits around the content.
- `.listRowBackground()` does fill the cell, but it doesn't animate.

Is there a way to animate a list row background?

Below is the source for full context. As written, because `listRowBackground` doesn't animate, you never see the background change at all. If you change it to `background` instead, it animates as expected but doesn't fill the cell.

```
struct Profile {
    let name: String
    var selected: Bool
    var hilited: Bool = false
}

extension Profile: Identifiable {
    var id: String { name }
}

struct ProfilesPicker: View {
    @State var profiles: [Profile]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<profiles.count) { index in
                let profile = profiles[index]

                CheckCell(name: profile.name, checked: profile.selected)
                    // using .background() gets a proper fade but doesn't fill the cell
                    .listRowBackground(Color(profile.hilited ? UIColor.systemFill : UIColor.systemBackground))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        profiles[index].hilited = true
                        withAnimation(.easeIn) {
                            profiles[index].hilited = false
                            profiles[index].selected.toggle()
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CheckCell: View {
    let name: String
    let checked: Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(name)
            Spacer()
            if checked {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
            }
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use delay and add animation to listRowBackground.

```
struct ProfilesPicker: View {
    @State var profiles: [Profile]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<profiles.count) { index in
                let profile = profiles[index]
                
                CheckCell(name: profile.name, checked: profile.selected)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        profiles[index].hilited = true
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { //<==Here
                            profiles[index].hilited = false
                            profiles[index].selected.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                    .animation(.default)
                    .listRowBackground(Color(profile.hilited ? UIColor.systemFill : UIColor.systemBackground).animation(.easeInOut)) //<==Here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works with one change, because I want it to be instantly gray and then fade to white: `Color(···).animate(profile.hilited ? .none : .easeOut)`